# enable clickling on parent tag with routerlink as child vue 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, routerlink

I have a `RouterLink` used inside a `li` tag and which basically makes a simple dropdown menu, When options are present on the dropdown menu I can click on the text to go to the next page but not click anywhere else inside the box, instead I want to be able to click on the whole  "bar" which is the `li` tag to be able to go to the page

```
<ul>
  <li v-for="product in products">
     <RouterLink :to="/product"> {{product}} </RouterLink>
  </li>
</ul>
```

this creates a dropdown like this:

|product name   |

|product 2 name  |

Now clicking on only text works but I want to be able to click inside the box as well. How do you solve that.
Another question is how do I close the dropdown when it is clicked anywhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The intuitive solution is to add click event handler to the `li` tag and use `$router.push('/product')` :

```html
<ul>
  <li v-for="product in products" @click="$router.push('/product')">
       {{product}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: how could i handle closing the dropdown when clicked anywhere outside the ul

Comment: Do you have installed Vueuse?

Comment: no, but i can do it if it provides a suitable solution

Comment: You could use this composable function https://vueuse.org/core/onclickoutside/#usage called onclickoutside